# What ip address do you use to connect to a VM from a Web App through point-to-site VNET Integration?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a .Net Web API deployed as a Web App and am trying to connect it to a MySQL db on a VM in a virtual network, but it's responding with a 500 internal server error.

My VNET just consists of one VM with no DNS or site-to-site configuration.

The preview portal says VNET Integration is connected, my certificates are in sync and the gateway is online.

I gave my VM a static IP address which I'm using in my web.config connection string, thinking requests would be routed through the gateway to the VM, but according to my general mysql log their aren't any connection attempts to the mysql server.

The address I gave my VM is within the range of addresses being routed to the VNET, and I setup an endpoint on the VM for the port I'm trying to connect to mysql on with an access rule that allows all connections, so I'm not sure why the connection doesn't appear to be getting through the gateway to my VM.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this link which provides instructions on how to connect Azure App Service - Web App with Azure Virtual Network, so that it can use resources visible within network itself:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

Comment: I went through this initially, but I'm not clear on what server address I'm supposed to use to make the connection. Do you know if giving your VM a static ip is necessary? This tutorial doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

App Service supports three ways to connect to VNETs.

1. ASE - (App Service Environment) is a dedicated Cloud Service that includes all the needed pieces for App Service and as such can be joined to a VNET. A good starting point on ASE is this blog (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-app-service-environment/).
2. Hybrid Connections - an agent based way to punch an application specific "wormhole" through network boundaries (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/)
3. Virtual Networks - a way to "dial up" from an App Service App into an network (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to resolve a specific connectivity issue for the Virtual Network Integration option. I did successfully connect to an on-premise db using Biztalk Hybrid Connections, but am exploring this other option because of serious latency issues Im experiencing with the Hybrid Connection.